# How to use multiple variables inside the Python for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm a Java guy, currently learned Python. I'm stuck on how to use multiple conditions
inside the Python for-loop.

here is the Java code

```
for (int r = n-1, s = k+1; r > s; r--, s++)
    // some code
```

How can I convert this into Python for-loop?

Comment: There is only for-in-loops in Python, you may generate a lazy sequence of all possibilities of r

Answer (score 5):

This can best be implemented as a `while` loop. It is more verbose than Java but also more Pythonic and, in my personal opinion, more readable:

```
r = n - 1
s = k + 1
while r > s:
    # some code
    r -= 1
    s += 1
```

Update: You *can* use a `for` loop but it's not as pretty:

```
p = (k + n) // 2
for r, s in zip(range(n - 1, p, -1), range(k + 1, p + 1)):
    # some code
```

Comment: thanks for your comment! I have another question. Is there any way to performs this task by using for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on doing it with a for loop, you can create a generator:

```
def gen(n, k):
    r = n - 1
    s = k + 1
    while r > s:
        yield (r, s)
        r -= 1
        s += 1

for x in gen(n, k):
    #some code

#alternatively:
for x, y in gen(n, k):
    #some code
```

Comment: Great idea, but: the generator should yield the tuple `(r, s)` so that these can be treated as loop variables, i.e. the consuming code would be `for r,s in gen(n, k)`. Also, the `yield r, s` should be before the increment and decrement of variables so that the first values mimic that of a for loop.

Comment: @mhawke You are absolutely right.  I modified my code.

Comment: I'd still change it to `for r, s in gen(n, k)` but that's up to the consumer to decide,

Comment: @mhawke Right. Done!